# Git rebase --skip recovery

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-rebase

I was working in a feature branch named `auth+menus`, below is the order of events and actions took that I need help trying to recover from. I'm fearing that I have lost all of my work, I hope I'm wrong.

`git commit -m "code changes"`

`git commit -m "more changes"`

`git rebase -i HEAD~2`

`git checkout master`

`git pull upstream master`

`git checkout auth+menus`

`git rebase master`

`git rebase --continue` A single conflict existed

`git rebase --skip`

`git add --all`

`git commit -m "some of these files should have already been committed"`

`git push origin auth+menu`

`git push origin auth+menu -f` since I'm an idiot...

I'm hoping that I have not totally lost everything that was in the first two commits, I really need someone's help with this! Is there a way to recover from this and get my original two commits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nah, you haven't lost anything. Do a `git reflog`. You will see something like:

```
33103ca HEAD@{0}: commit: Using arguments on command line to specify revision ra
46d9365 HEAD@{1}: commit: more changes
1dfdc0d HEAD@{2}: commit: code changes
31a16ad HEAD@{3}: merge test2: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
1dfdc0d HEAD@{4}: commit: .
ddc65bf HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from test2 to master
236c36d HEAD@{6}: commit: .
ddc65bf HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from master to test2
ddc65bf HEAD@{8}: commit: .
be347db HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from be347db616c39dadad59308bee5736e5614e7d61
```

Well, it may not look a lot like that, but the key is to find the line that says "commit: more changes". Go ahead and tag that sucker; in this case, it would be `git tag mytag HEAD@{1}`. Then you can merge in that tag, cherry pick it, or whatever.

Comment: BTW @DavidPine, in general you don't want to use `-f` with `git push`. If you are working with other people, it will rarely do what you think it will.

Comment: I'm having issues with `git tag`, it doesn't like this "`git tag safety HEAD@{9}`"

Comment: @DavidPine - what doesn't it like? What error message are you getting?

Comment: `git tag safety HEAD@{9}
error: unknown switch `e'` I think it's this... https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/106

Comment: @DavidPine, Hmmm, I have no idea why you are getting that. I mean, you aren't passing any switch to `git tag`.  Maybe try creating a branch off of `HEAD@{9}`, or merging it into the current branch? Important thing is, your commits are in the reflog, so they have not been lost.

Comment: @DavidPine, sorry, but I'm just about to crash. If nobody comes to your aid, I'll definitely revisit this in the morning. But know that your commits are not lost.